# Visual Studio 2012 not debugging or compiling one specific method

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

My debugger in VS 2012 will not break at any breakpoints in only one specific method in a class.  It also wont step into that method from any calling code.

Other methods in that class are stepping into just fine.  Even if I make changes to those methods and recompile, I can still step through them.  If I make changes to this one specific method, they are NOT realised.  It seems to be using an old version of this method... which is extremely weird.

I have tried everything mentioned in this [comprehensive thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649093/visual-studio-2010-debugger-steps-over-methods-and-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoints).

My breakpoints are solid red - they do NOT have the "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No Symbols have been loaded for this document" error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do the class have base or derived classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing.

The reason is that my method was [yield returning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) an `IEnumerable` and I hadn't began iterating through the stream on the client side, so obviously any breakpoints in my method would not be hit yet.