# Visual Studio Cant Find File - Debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

During debugging in Visual Studio 2015 it cant find files:

```
xxxx.cs not found
You need to find xxx.cs to view the source for the current call stack frame

Try one of the following options:
- Browse and find xxx.cs

You can view disassembly in the Dissasembly window. To alsways view dissassembly for the missing source files, change the setting in the Options dialog
```

The .cs file in question is from a third party dll, so I do not expect to be able to step through it. It seems to be acting as though I am not in debug, but I am, and I have  in the web.config. I have tried a million settings in VS, but nothing seems to help. For example:

Enable Just My Code is unchecked
Adding the files to the 'Do not look for these source files' list makes it stop asking where file is, but I still get the 'xxx.cs not found' tab

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you step out of or over the call to the third party library and continue debugging?

Comment: If I step over it gets past that screen. But in the course of trying to debug something it hist like 100 things in the third party dlls. So debugging is basically useless

Comment: If you call a function from the third party, you should be able to step over that function and continue with your own source code? You could also set a break point directly after the third party function is called and run until the breakpoint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967736/random-cs-files-not-opening-in-visual-studio-2012

Otherwise have you tried removing and re-adding the .dll?  In most cases (especially when using TFS or any other VCS it breaks a lot of my references to third party .dll's and projects)

Comment: Its the same issue, but there is no accepted answer on that question, and I have tried all but the last option, which I am very resistant to

Comment: The project has to be built with a symbol table so the debugger can link assembled code to the source code to the assembled instructions.

Comment: If you mean .pdb file, then yes, the dll in question has one.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a very stupid answer, and you have probably already found a better one.

If you're trying to prevent Visual Studio from stepping through non-user code, you have to delete the .pdb for the dll and enable Just My Code in your options.