# StorageCredentials.cs not found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I'm using WindowsAzure.Storage, in a .NET CORE 2.0 library (dll) but when I unit test I get StorageCredentials.cs not found.

```
 public class AzureFileStorage : IDocumentStorage
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
    CloudFileClient fileClient;
    StorageCredentials credit;

    public AzureFileStorage()
    {
        credit = new StorageCredentials(appSettings.Current.Settigns["azAccountName"],appSettings.Current.Settigns["keyValue"]);
        storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credit, true);
        fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
    }
}
```

I can navigate tot he file and the file/class is there, Am I missing something?
[image]

Also, the path starting C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\ is nowhere to find on my computer.

Comment: Is it in another namespace?

Comment: @Jerodev everything is in the same namespace and project.

Comment: what u mean 'StorageCredentials.cs'? THats a file name. Can u paste the exact error message please

Comment: @pm100 added img with error

Comment: If there is a reproduced demo project will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

According to your error message, I suppose the issue is related with Debug settings.

There are some ways you could have a try.

1.Open **Tools>Debugging>General**>tick **Enable Just My Code**. For more details, please refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901736/mvvm-light-obtained-via-nuget-relaycommand-cs-not-found).

2.Right click "**Solution** >**Properties** and then go to "**Debug Source Files**". Check under "Do not look for these source files" window if you have your problematic file path written in it.  For more details, please refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791669/there-is-no-source-available-for-the-current-location).

[image]

3. Uncheck [Enable source server support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806993/no-source-available) in Debugging/General.

[image]

4.The system  has a **StorageCredentials** class. After I have installed **WindowsAzure.Storage** nuget package(like 8.7.0), I could use this class by adding `using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth` reference;

5.**.Net core 2.0 compatibility**.I also meet a similar [error](https://image.ibb.co/mNsOUc/json_Not_Fould.png) like you. Just the class is different. Above the package is an **exclamation mark**. It says this [package version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/5.2.2) can not support .NET Standard 2.0. It supports in 
 [version 5.2.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/5.2.4). You know the standard 2.0 is new, there  are still some features  can not support in it. You could also check your package dependencies of compatibility. If your error is this, you could to wait for core 2.0 to update to support for some packages. Or  choose a **compatible version** of packages.

[image]

Comment: @Victor A Chavez I have updated my answer. I met a similar error in solution 5. You could refer to.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, you could vote it up or mark it as answer to help other community members. Thanks!