# getting label to show on button click and disappear after several seconds

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. It is giving me this error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined"

```
  var timeoutID;

function delayedAlert() {
    document.getElementById('<%= Label3.ClientID %>').style.display = 'inherit';
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(labelhide, 3000);
}

function labelhide() {
    document.getElementById('<%= Label3.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
}
```

button code

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Onclick = "Button1_Click" 
            OnClientClick = "javascript:delayedAlert(); return SubmitForm();" 
            Text="Submit" Width="98px"
```

This is my Label3

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Entry Successful!" Visible="False" ForeColor="Lime"></asp:Label>
```

This is what the new error says with the code above..
[image]

Comment: Check your rendered HTML, what is the ID of the supposed `Label3`

Comment: Can we see the code for Label3? It can't find Label3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because the element `Label3` could not be found. Please verify that you have `ClientIDMode="Static"` in the Label declaration. If not, you must use `ClientID`, like this:

```
document.getElementById('<%= Label3.ClientID %>').style.display = 'inherit';
```

Comment: I just set the CLientIDMode in the label declaration and it not working, I used the 2nd method as well and it doesn't work as well D:

Comment: @user2484066 ClientIDMode="Static" can only be used in .NET 4.0 or greater. The other alternative should work, don't forget to add it in both functions: delayedAlert and labelhide

Comment: @user2484066 that's unrelated to this problem. Anyway, try to clean/rebuild, this might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314329/getting-rid-of-there-is-no-source-code-available-for-the-current-location