# Bug in Visual Studio 2015 on Debug Source Files tab?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Looking in other places on the web, it looks like the "Debug Source Files" tab is supposed to give a list of source files that are being ignored by Visual Studio.  However in my Visual Studio 2015 community edition, this is what I see for that tab:

[image: Tab contents]

This is exactly the same as appears for the "Configuration" tab making me think this is a bug in Visual Studio 2015.  Does anyone else get this?

Comment: Huh, *"Debug Source Files" tab is supposed to give a list of source files that are being ignored by Visual Studio* - no  that is not what the tab is for. Its for changing projects: config mode, platform target and if its to be built and deployed.

Comment: Then look at the screenshots in this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314329/getting-rid-of-there-is-no-source-code-available-for-the-current-location?rq=1

Comment: any reason you aren't using vs2017?

Comment: You're getting confused that is to do with Symbols - Program DataBase (PDB) Files as per the screenshot in the answer...

Comment: @JeremyThompson Well then why not give a through answer to this question because I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: *Looking in other places on the web, it looks like the "Debug Source Files" tab is supposed to give a list of source files that are being ignored by Visual Studio.* - **where did you hear or see this?** Its incorrect. What do you really want? To see "Excluded Files"? What is the Bug?
 What is the expected behaviour of this bug?

Comment: I want to see a list of source files that are being ignored by visual studio during debugging.

Comment: Well, you are right, this is not what the dialog looks like.  You should see two boxes, the top one lists the directories where the debugger looks for source files, the bottom one allows you to add files that should be ignored.  Not a VS2015 bug, your machine is wonky.  Nothing that a disk reformat could not fix, you can spin the update/repair/reinstall wheel of fortune to perhaps not make it as painful.  Nothing anybody here can do to make it less of a pain.

Comment: @Jez, So a simple C# Console app, it still has this issue in your solution property, am I right? Maybe you could share us your Environment, I will check it, I installed the VS 2015 in windows 10, it was installed in the default C drive disk(System disk). So if possible, please check that whether you install your VS in the default path, please also update your VS2015 to the latest version( the latest update 3), view the result. Actually I think it was a setup issue. Maybe you could collect the setup log messages in your side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug in the first version of Visual Studio 2015.  I upgraded to Update 3, and now the dialog shows correctly:

[image: Dialog image]

Comment: Since it was resolved, would you please mark it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issue to find the answer easily, and we could close this case. Have a nice day:)

Comment: I will now.  I would've before but SO prevents you marking your answer correct too quickly.